# perl get matched pattern in text file

Tags: regex, file, perl

I want to get value of -cfg from a file. Need help on the regex.

File Contain:

```
### Full Command: /some/path/ -cfg abc123/123def ###
```

Expected output:
`abc123/123def`

Code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $file="file.txt"
open(F, '<', $file) or die "cannot open $file";

while (<F>) {
   chomp;
   if (/-cfg\s([a-zA-Z0-9_.]*)\s/) {
     $value=$1;
               print "Config: $value";
   }
}
close F;
```

Answer (score 4):

The regex pattern is missing the `/`, which is in the string to match (`abc123/123def`).  Since the pattern delimiters are `/`, inside the pattern the `/` must be escaped

```
/-cfg\s([a-zA-Z0-9_.\/]*)\s/
```

Or, you can change delimiters to nearly anything, and then we do need the `m` in front

```
m{-cfg\s([a-zA-Z0-9_./]*)\s}
```

If you only need ASCII can use `\w` for a "word character" (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)<sup>†</sup> and this simplifies

```
m{-cfg\s([\w./]*)\s}
```

It also makes it easier to see at a glance what we match (a word character and `.` and `/`).

I'd like to add, the `/x` [modifier](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Modifiers) is often a real blessing, making it ignore spaces (and newlines and `#`-comments) so that patterns can be spread out for readability

```
m{ -cfg \s ([\w./]*) \s }x
```

References: tutorial [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut) and the full reference [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre).  The [perlrebackslash](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash) is often handy.

---

Comments on the program in the question

- The program won't run though because `$value` is undeclared, for what [strict pragma](https://perldoc.perl.org/strict) will stop it in compilation.  Need

  ```
  my $value = $1;
  ```
- Better use lexical filehandles, `open my $fh, '<', $file ...`.  See [perlopentut](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.14.0/perlopentut) and reference [open](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open). (Also, ["bareword filehandles"](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open#Assigning-a-filehandle-to-a-bareword) won't work by default starting from v5.36.0.)
- Always print the actual error, most of the time using the `$!` [error variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#Error-Variables). Altogether

  ```
  open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";
  ```

---

<sup>†</sup> Really any alphanumeric character (and `_`), 100_000+ characters in Unicode they say

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would write that, assuming that I want to get the first match in the file and not any subsequent matches:

```
while (<DATA>) {
    next unless / \s -cfg \s+ (\S+) /x;
    print "Config: $1\n";
    last;
    }

__END__
This is a line
Another line
Not this line
### Full Command: /some/path/ -cofg xyz/123def ###
### Full Command: /some/path/ -cfg abc123/123def ###
### Full Command: /some/path/ -cfg 123abc/123def ###
```

If you want to get matches beyond the first line to match, take out the last.

This program's structure is very common. Skip all the lines until you reach the one you want, then use the rest of the loop to process that single line. I don't need to `chomp` lines I don't care about, and I don't even need to `chomp` those I do care about since my regex extracts what I need.

Since I've already done the match in the line with `next`, I can use its captures to get the values that I want.

If the argument for `-cfg` can be more complicated or have quoted values, I'd do something not as simple. First, I'd have the same structure where I skip lines. Instead of matching a single value, I'd extract the entire command and pass that to `shellwords`, which knows how to parse command lines:

```
use v5.10;
use Text::ParseWords qw(shellwords);

while (<DATA>) {
    next unless / \A
        \#\#\# \s+ Full \s+ Command:
        (.+)
        \#\#\#
        /x;
    my $shellwords = join "\0", shellwords($1); # because I'm lazy
    next unless $shellwords =~ /\0 -cfg \0 ([^\0]+) /x;
    say "Config: $1";
    last;
    }
__END__
This is a line
Another line
Not this line
### Full Command: /some/path/ -cofg xyz/123def ###
### Full Command: /some/path/ -cfg "abc123 123def" ###
### Full Command: /some/path/ -cfg 123abc/123def ###
```

The output shows I correctly picked up the quoted value:

```
Config: abc123 123def
```

This code is slightly clever because I'm lazy. I want to find the value in a list immediately after another list. I could walk the list until I find the right value then take the next one. Instead, I join all the elements on something that shouldn't be there—a null byte–then look for `-cfg` between null bytes and the thing after that. That's not an important part of the problem and you could look at the list from `shellwords` however you like.